# How to reduce serial speed on Arduino bootloader (optiboot) and on the IDE?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide, bootloader

I'm [debugging a couple of RS232-to-TTL converter boards](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/104466/29792) that I'm trying to use to program my Arduinos and one thing I would like to try would be to reduce the upload serial speed from 115200 to 19200.

**How do I do that?**

I imagine that there's a setting that can be easily changed on the Arduino IDE preferences. But where is it? But then the bootloader speed would have to match that? **How do I change the serial upload speed on optiboot, too?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Arduino IDE side, the upload speed is coded in `hardware/arduino/boards.txt`

```
uno.upload.speed=115200
...
```

for every kind of board; you cannot change it directly from the IDE (that would be too dangerous as that value must match the **expected speed for the actual bootloader** of every board).

Now as per the optiboot loader side, the upload speed is defined in `BAUD_RATE` macro, in `optiboot.c`:

```
/* set the UART baud rate defaults */
#ifndef BAUD_RATE
#if F_CPU >= 8000000L
#define BAUD_RATE   115200L // Highest rate Avrdude win32 will support
#elsif F_CPU >= 1000000L
#define BAUD_RATE   9600L   // 19200 also supported, but with significant error
#elsif F_CPU >= 128000L
#define BAUD_RATE   4800L   // Good for 128kHz internal RC
#else
#define BAUD_RATE 1200L     // Good even at 32768Hz
#endif
#endif
```

So I guess you can:

1. `#define BAUD_RATE 19200` before that block of code
2. recompile the optiboot loader
3. upload your own new bootloader version
4. update `uno.upload.speed` accordingly in `boards.txt`
5. check it on the usual blink sketch and cross your fingers :-)

Please note that this kind of task is not for beginners, you need to know what you're doing.
Also note that I disclaim any responsibility if you get unable to upload programs to your Arduino afterwards!

Comment: This isn't going to "fry" your arduino. At worst, you'd wind up with a ATmega with a 
damaged boot loader, which would just mean you'd need to re-program it again via ICSP.

Comment: Then say you could render your arduino unrecoverable without a proper programmer. "Fry" implies actual hardware damage, not just mis-configuration that makes recovery involved.

Comment: no proprer progrqammer is needed, you can use ftdi/8u2 chip on-board with bit-bang mode.

Comment: Tried it and it worked great! Well, the Uno didn't like the optiboot running on 56200 bps (not sure why), but the Severino and my custom boards with serial FTDI-like programming headers all worked. I also couldn't compile the optiboot slower than that (tried 19200) because other compile errors, but that's ok. I used Arduino IDE 1.0.5 and followed the instructions on .\hardware\arduino\bootloaders\optiboot\README.TXT and didn't have to install anything beyond the IDE. Nice!!

Comment: And that solved the problem with my RS232-to-TTL converter board. It worked ok with 56200 bps. Thanks much!!